# Can I use Sass with a batch script in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, batch-file, sass

In web projects on my local machine, I'm using a fairly simple Sass setup.
In the same folder, I have /scss/style.scss and /css/style.css

So to run Sass while I work I just write this in a Ruby Terminal:

```
cd "C:\Users\Puppybeard\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Project Title"
sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css
```

Works fine, but it's a little cumbersome, so I'm trying to figure out how to do the equivalent with a batch script.
I've tried the following, but it's a complete disaster, and my computer tries to open an infinite amount of Ruby consoles.

```
cd "C:\Ruby193\bin"
start ruby
cd "C:\Users\Puppybeard\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Project Title"
sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css
exit
```

I think what I need to do is to start Ruby running in the background, rather than open the Ruby exe. Does anyone know how, or is that even how Ruby works? Obviously, I'm new to Sass, Ruby and batch scripts, so any insight you can give me would be a big help, thanks.

---

EDIT: I got it working like this

```
cd "\Ruby193\bin"
sass --watch "C:\Users\Puppybeard\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Project Title\scss\style.scss:C:\Users\Puppybeard\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Project Title\css\style.css"
```

I think it should be neater, and suspect that sass needs to have it's $PATH set.

---

EDIT 2: I set the Path variable for Ruby, using these instructions: http://groups.google.com/group/beginning-rails/browse_thread/thread/1c68665013a60081

In my case, the path I needed to add was C:\Ruby193\bin
Now the only line I need, when I have the script in the root of the web project, is:

> sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css

I could keep the part where I change directory to the location of the folders in if I wanted to have something that can run from anywhere on my computer. However, the fact that the script doesn't specify the project location means I can just copy it into any project where I use the same structure.

Worth the effort? In the long run, probably, yeah.

Comment: You can do using the Ruby CMD Prompt, and just running `sass --watch`.

Comment: I know, that's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your original two commands into your batch file. So the content of the .bat file would be:

```
cd "C:\Users\Puppybeard\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Project Title"
sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css
```

Simple as that. A batch file like this runs each command on each line one after the other, as if you were typing each one individually.

Comment: Hmm I think that'd be the right answer if I'd set up Sass properly. Looking into setting the $PATH for it now.

Comment: You don't need Sass in the path, only Ruby. Sass is a Rubygem and so if Ruby and gems are set up correctly running the sass command from anywhere on your filesystem will work. To check, have a look in \Ruby193\bin for the sass.bat file. Then check to make sure that \Ruby193\bin is in your path. When you install sass, the executable files that run it are automatically installed in Ruby's bin folder like this.

Comment: Yep it was the Path all right. It only needs one command now! Cheers.

Comment: Note that if `sass` is a batch file you have to use `call sass` if you want more lines to run after that.

Comment: @Joey thanks for that! Here is the batch file I've been using: 
https://gist.github.com/dieseltravis/4991031

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I found the solution was to replace `sass --watch styles.scss:styles.css` with `ruby C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/sass --watch styles.scss:../../css/styles.css`. So just prefix the standard sass command with the path directory to your sass installation.

Comment: @edwinbradford's comment caused it working. Thanks Edwin.

Comment: Note that naming your batch file sass.bat is not a good idea if you're calling sass in the batch file.

Answer (score 2):

**If you're trying to update multiple css files with a batch file** like this:

```
scss A.scss ../CSS/A.css
scss B.scss ../CSS/B.css
echo Done.
```

...but only the first scss command line executes, and the batch file never completes, i.e. you never see the 'Done.', here is why and how to fix it:

scss is actually a buggy batch file that fails to return control to your batch file.  I fixed this by bypassing the scss batch file and runing ruby and it's scss gem directly as follows:

```
ruby C:/Ruby193/bin/scss A.scss ../CSS/A.css
ruby C:/Ruby193/bin/scss B.scss ../CSS/B.css
echo Done.
```

You'll need to have your path pointed to ruby, or put an absolute path in above.

Comment: Sass is still buggy, to put in your BAT files simply invoke them via CALL like "call sass..." I hoe this helps